# Array Multidimensional in Javascript split to two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, graph

I have an array returned from ajax (data) and i need split to two:

An alert from data returns:

> [[200326,150000],[200327,150000],[200328,150000],[200329,150000],[200330,160000],[200331,320000]]

I try run this code to get into dates first elements like 200326...200331 and get into prices second element:

```
var dates = [];
var prices= [];
var datason = JSON.parse("[" + data + "]");
for (var i in datason) {
    dates.push(datason[i][0]);
    prices.push(datason[i][1]);
}
```

Alert from datason returns:

> 200326,150000,200327,150000,200328,150000,200329,150000,200330,160000,200331,320000

Then I want show a canvas graph:

```
var chartdata = {
                        labels: dates,
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: 'Evolution',
                                backgroundColor: '#49e2ff',
                                borderColor: '#46d5f1',
                                hoverBackgroundColor: '#CCCCCC',
                                hoverBorderColor: '#666666',
                                data: prices
                            }
                        ]
                    };
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to add those extra `[` and `]`. They are already present in your data.

Try this way:

```
var dates = [];
var prices= [];
var datason = JSON.parse(data);
for (var i in datason) {
    dates.push(datason[i][0]);
    prices.push(datason[i][1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I get needed values on.

Answer (score 1):

i guess, this code will help you

```js
const data = [[200326,150000],[200327,150000],[200328,150000],[200329,150000],[200330,160000],[200331,320000]];

const { dates, prices } = data.reduce(
  ({ dates, prices }, current) => ({ 
    dates: [ ...dates, current[0]],
    prices: [ ...prices, current[1]]
  }), 
  { dates: [], prices: [] }
);

console.log(dates);
console.log(prices);
```